# How do I provide input to a C program from bash?

Tags: c, bash

I have been reading a ton about bash scripts and program testing but I am still unable to make this code work.

Basically it is a simple program that asks the user for either of `north` `east` `south` or `west`. I start the program then it immediately asks for input. I just can not get the bash script to give it any input. I tried using `echo` and `expect`.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the function used to get the players input:

```
int process_input(Map *game)
{
    printf("\n> ");

    char ch = getchar();
    char a = getchar(); //eat enter

    int damage = rand() % 4;

    switch(ch) {

        case -1:
            printf("you suck\n");
            return 0;
            break;
        case 'n':
            game->proto.move(game, NORTH);
            break;
        case 's':
            game->_(move)(game, SOUTH);
            break;
        case 'e':
            game->_(move)(game, EAST);
            break;
        case 'w':
            game->_(move)(game, WEST);
            break;
        case 'a':
            game->_(attack)(game, damage);
            break;
        case 'l':
                    printf("You can go:\n");
                    if(game->location->north) printf("NORTH\n");
                    if(game->location->south) printf("SOUTH\n");
                    if(game->location->east) printf("EAST\n");
                if(game->location->west) printf("WEST\n");
                    break;
        default:
            printf("Whats next?", ch);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

And here is the attempt at a bash script:

```
   #!/bin/bash
    /Desktop/c
    ./ex17 echo 'w'
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?  Create a C program, or a bash script?

Comment: are you trying to send the input to the `c program` through a `bash script`?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want/ask, and it looks like I'm not alone.

Comment: Yes I am trying to send input into this program with a bash script.

Comment: @blankwall show what you've done in the bash script? it's easy enough to feed it lines in bash  ALSO show your main() in C

Comment: aah ... okay you need to learn how to do command line arguments as well as piping.  Show your main() as well please :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can feed input into a program from bash using any of the following mechanisms.

For a single line of input, you can use a *here-string*:

```
./ex17 <<<'w'
```

For multiple lines, you can use a *here-document*:

```
./ex17 <<'EOF'
w
second line of input
more input
EOF
```

Or you can move those lines out of the script and into a separate file:

```
./ex17 <filename
```

More generally, you can run a command that generates as its output the desired input to your program, and connect them together with a *pipe*.  For instance, the above could also be written:

```
cat filename | ./ex17
```

or the original example as

```
echo w | ./ex17
```

That's more general because you can replace `cat` and `echo` here with any sort of program, which can do all sorts of computation to determine what it outputs instead of just dumping the contents of a static string or file.

But what you can't easily do from bash is drive input, read output, and make decisions about what to send as the next input.  For that, you should look at [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).  An expect script would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn ./ex17
expect ">"
send "w\n"
expect "Whats next?"
send "next line here\n"
# turn it back over to interactive user
interact
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this: first:

```
 echo w | ./ex17
```

This will send w to the example and output the move.  This is called piping; and it essentially connects the stdout of echo to the stdin of ex17

Answer (score -1):

You can do either a `C` code or a `Bash` script, not a mixed one.
Use `scanf()` for reading from keyboard (it stops reading when you hit ENTER) and complete this code in `C` language.

Comment: he's trying to feed input from bash into his C program which is perfectly possible