# using "ask dialog" command to immediately pass text through Bash command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, ask-cli

I want to use the "ask dialog" command to immediately pass a question. I am trying to automate the process of launching terminal and running "ask dialog". Whenever my bash script runs, it pauses once the Alexa instance opens.

```
#!/bin/bash/
cd /Users/AlexaDirectory/
ask dialog 
#this is where I need to ask Alexa a question automatically. 
#I have tried running "ask dialog && (insert question)", but the script pauses once it reaches "ask dialog"
echo "end"
```

Here's what i usually see when running the .sh

```
MacBook-Pro Desktop % bash Test.command
Defaulting locale to the first value from the skill manifest: en-US

======================================= Welcome to ASK Dialog =======================================
=========== In interactive mode, type your utterance text onto the console and hit enter ============
===================== Alexa will then evaluate your input and give a response! ======================
=== Use ".record <fileName>" or ".record <fileName> --append-quit" to save list of utterances to a file. ===
=============== You can exit the interactive mode by entering ".quit" or "ctrl + c". ================

User  >
```

If it is not possible to pass a question immediately, would it be possible to send keystrokes to the terminal?

Comment: I'm _guessing_ you want something like `expect` (a scripting language built on top of TCL that's specialized to automate other programs, reading their output and writing to their input) -- although that's exactly the opposite of what your title asks for. Although maybe you want a heredoc, to be able to write text to `ask`'s stdin? It's very unclear what you _actually want_, so it's not clear how to answer.

Comment: ...when you say "pass text through bash command" -- *which* text, specifically, should be passed through *which* bash command?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry I'm very new to shell, as in I'm learning it specifically for this small project. I will look into that. As for how the question is phrased, I don't entirely understand what i'm working with or how the 'ask' command works, so its difficult to explain what I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Backing up: When you say "pass a question", do you want your question to be written _to the `ask` command_? (If so, what you want is probably a heredoc: `ask <<EOF`, then your question text, then `EOF`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy After the 'ask dialog' is invoked, it brings up the 'Welcome to Ask Dialog'. I am trying to basically paste text into the command line from there.

Comment: Great -- sounds like a heredoc really is what you want, then; we do have several Q&A entries describing how to do that.

Comment: See f/e the answer to [How do I provide input to a C program from bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508817/how-do-i-provide-input-to-a-c-program-from-bash) -- note that while the question goes into a lot of C-specific detail, the answer is quite generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Charles Duffy, using a herestring is the answer.

The process freezes when the `ask dialog` is invoked, and the fix is sending `ask dialog <<< "question for alexa placed here"`. This immediately ends the Alexa instance too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [the `expect` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). I've been struggling with a similar problem. Running `ask init` in non-interactive mode. In the end I solved it like this.

```sh
echo '#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn ask init 
expect "? Skill Id (leave empty to create one):" 
send "my-skill\r" 
expect "? Skill package path:" 
send "./path/to/skill-package\r" 
expect "? Lambda code path for default region (leave empty to not deploy Lambda):" 
send "./path/to/lampda-package\r"
' > ask_init.sh
chmod u+x ask_init.sh 
./ask_init.sh
```

FYI, I had also tried piping answers to it using a combination of `|` and `echo`, like this:

```sh
echo 'quantum-skill
./path/to/skill-package
./path/to/lampda-package
' | ask init
```

and with `printf`, like this:

```sh
printf 'quantum-skill\n./path/to/skill-package\n./path/to/lambda-package\n' | ask init
```

Neither one of the latter worked. So I recommend using `expect` instead.